# Validate Date entered into a DataGridView

Tags: c#, winforms, validation, datagridview

I am trying to validate an entered `Date` value in a `DataGridViewCell` by users and if the value does not match the a specific scheme, it should give the user a message like

> entered value should match dd/MM/yyyy format

I tried below code on `CellValidating` event

```
private void DGV_PatientSessions_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (DGV_PatientSessions.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "DGV_PatientSessions_Date")
    {
        string DateValue;
        DateTime DateFormated;
        DateValue = DGV_PatientSessions.CurrentRow.Cells["DGV_PatientSessions_Date"].Value.ToString();
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(DateValue, "dd/MM/yyyy", new CultureInfo("ar-SY"), DateTimeStyles.None, out DateFormated))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("done");
        }
    }
}
```

but I still get message error below

[image]

I tried to use regex which not recommended as I found when I searched but it wont work

```
string DateFormat;
DateFormat = DGV_PatientSessions.CurrentRow.Cells["DGV_PatientSessions_Date"].Value.ToString();
if(Regex.IsMatch(DateFormat, @"(0[1-9]|[12][0-9]|3[01])[- /.](0[1-9]|1[012])[- /.](19|20)\d\d$"))
{
    MessageBox.Show("done");
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show("value should match dd/MM/yyyy format);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to cancel the edit if the data entered is not valid using `e.Cancel = true;`:

```
private void DGV_PatientSessions_CellValidating(object sender, DataGridViewCellValidatingEventArgs e)
{
    if (DGV_PatientSessions.Columns[e.ColumnIndex].Name == "DGV_PatientSessions_Date")
    {
        string DateValue;
        DateTime DateFormated;
        DateValue = DGV_PatientSessions.CurrentRow.Cells["DGV_PatientSessions_Date"].Value.ToString();
        if (DateTime.TryParseExact(DateValue, "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out DateFormated))
        {
            MessageBox.Show("done");
        } 
        else 
        {
            MessageBox.Show("value should match dd/MM/yyyy format");
            e.Cancel = true; // The important part
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I give it a try and now I am getting the else part always and I am not able to enter data even if the cell in `datagridview` is null in short word validation is always false

Comment: @sam Sorry I didn't double-check your DateTime parse test to see if you were doing it correctly. Provided that you are, this is how you handle it. I'm guessing that you are not, which would be a completely different and separate question.

Comment: @sam I edited my answer to use `CultureInfo.InvariantCulture'--see if that makes a difference.

Comment: same issue nothing changed